# Flex 4 Show Interactive Container on MouseOver

Tags: flex4, flash-builder

Currently i'm trying to create a container B which is within another container A.
Container B is invisible by default, when entering container A it is supposed to turn visible and be interactive. (imagine container B as a button)

i'm using the following code

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        protected function mouseOverHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            this.voter.conB = true;
            this.voter.conB = true;
            this.addElement(this.conB);
        }

        protected function mouseOutHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            this.conB.visible = false;
            this.conB.enabled = false;
            this.addElement(this.conA);
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

    <s:element id="conB" visible="false"/>
    <s:element id="conA" mouseOver="mouseOverHandler(event)" mouseOut="mouseOutHandler(event)"/>
```

Basicly its working, the problem that i have is that when i roll over containerB then flex counts that as mouseOutEvent from container A, which makes containerB invisible again, than again the mouse is on container A since B is invisible and B again gets triggered visible. 
the result is a flicker effect on container b, which also makes it impossible to click the button within container b.

any ideas how to solve that problem / another way to realize what i intend?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm no thats not the problem.

here what the code looks like:

basicly i tested it with a custom skin (here named "test") for the spark button class, here what it looks like, but like i said its the **unedited** pure auto-generated flex code when defining a new skin for the spark button class

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!--

    ADOBE SYSTEMS INCORPORATED
    Copyright 2008 Adobe Systems Incorporated
    All Rights Reserved.

    NOTICE: Adobe permits you to use, modify, and distribute this file
    in accordance with the terms of the license agreement accompanying it.

-->

<!--- The default skin class for the Spark Button component.  

       @see spark.components.Button

      @langversion 3.0
      @playerversion Flash 10
      @playerversion AIR 1.5
      @productversion Flex 4
-->
<s:SparkSkin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
             xmlns:fb="http://ns.adobe.com/flashbuilder/2009" minWidth="21" minHeight="21" alpha.disabled="0.5">

    <!-- host component -->
    <fx:Metadata>
        <![CDATA[ 
        /** 
         * @copy spark.skins.spark.ApplicationSkin#hostComponent
         */
        [HostComponent("spark.components.Button")]
        ]]>
    </fx:Metadata>

    <fx:Script fb:purpose="styling">
        <![CDATA[         
            /* Define the skin elements that should not be colorized. 
            For button, the graphics are colorized but the label is not. */
            static private const exclusions:Array = ["labelDisplay"];

            /** 
             * @private
             */     
            override public function get colorizeExclusions():Array {return exclusions;}

            /**
             * @private
             */
            override protected function initializationComplete():void
            {
                useChromeColor = true;
                super.initializationComplete();
            }  

            /**
             *  @private
             */
            override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number) : void
            {
                var cr:Number = getStyle("cornerRadius");

                if (cornerRadius != cr)
                {
                    cornerRadius = cr;
                    shadow.radiusX = cornerRadius;
                    fill.radiusX = cornerRadius;
                    lowlight.radiusX = cornerRadius;
                    highlight.radiusX = cornerRadius;
                    border.radiusX = cornerRadius;
                }

                if (highlightStroke) highlightStroke.radiusX = cornerRadius;
                if (hldownstroke1) hldownstroke1.radiusX = cornerRadius;
                if (hldownstroke2) hldownstroke2.radiusX = cornerRadius;

                super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
            }

            private var cornerRadius:Number = 2;
        ]]>        
    </fx:Script>

    <!-- states -->
    <s:states>
        <s:State name="up" />
        <s:State name="over" />
        <s:State name="down" />
        <s:State name="disabled" />
    </s:states>

    <!-- layer 1: shadow -->
    <!--- @private -->
    <s:Rect id="shadow" left="-1" right="-1" top="-1" bottom="-1" radiusX="2">
        <s:fill>
            <s:LinearGradient rotation="90">
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" 
                                 color.down="0xFFFFFF"
                                 alpha="0.01"
                                 alpha.down="0" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" 
                                 color.down="0xFFFFFF" 
                                 alpha="0.07"
                                 alpha.down="0.5" />
            </s:LinearGradient>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>

    <!-- layer 2: fill -->
    <!--- @private -->
    <s:Rect id="fill" left="1" right="1" top="1" bottom="1" radiusX="2">
        <s:fill>
            <s:LinearGradient rotation="90">
                <s:GradientEntry color="0xFFFFFF" 
                                 color.over="0xBBBDBD" 
                                 color.down="0xAAAAAA" 
                                 alpha="0.85" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0xD8D8D8" 
                                 color.over="0x9FA0A1" 
                                 color.down="0x929496" 
                                 alpha="0.85" />
            </s:LinearGradient>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>

    <!-- layer 3: fill lowlight -->
    <!--- @private -->
    <s:Rect id="lowlight" left="1" right="1" top="1" bottom="1" radiusX="2">
        <s:fill>
            <s:LinearGradient rotation="270">
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" ratio="0.0" alpha="0.0627" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" ratio="0.48" alpha="0.0099" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" ratio="0.48001" alpha="0" />
            </s:LinearGradient>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>

    <!-- layer 4: fill highlight -->
    <!--- @private -->
    <s:Rect id="highlight" left="1" right="1" top="1" bottom="1" radiusX="2">
        <s:fill>
            <s:LinearGradient rotation="90">
                <s:GradientEntry color="0xFFFFFF"
                                 ratio="0.0"
                                 alpha="0.33" 
                                 alpha.over="0.22" 
                                 alpha.down="0.12"/>
                <s:GradientEntry color="0xFFFFFF"
                                 ratio="0.48"
                                 alpha="0.33"
                                 alpha.over="0.22"
                                 alpha.down="0.12" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0xFFFFFF"
                                 ratio="0.48001"
                                 alpha="0" />
            </s:LinearGradient>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>

    <!-- layer 5: highlight stroke (all states except down) -->
    <!--- @private -->
    <s:Rect id="highlightStroke" left="1" right="1" top="1" bottom="1" radiusX="2" excludeFrom="down">
        <s:stroke>
            <s:LinearGradientStroke rotation="90" weight="1">
                <s:GradientEntry color="0xFFFFFF" alpha.over="0.22" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0xD8D8D8" alpha.over="0.22" />
            </s:LinearGradientStroke>
        </s:stroke>
    </s:Rect>

    <!-- layer 6: highlight stroke (down state only) -->
    <!--- @private -->
    <s:Rect id="hldownstroke1" left="1" right="1" top="1" bottom="1" radiusX="2" includeIn="down">
        <s:stroke>
            <s:LinearGradientStroke rotation="90" weight="1">
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" alpha="0.25" ratio="0.0" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" alpha="0.25" ratio="0.001" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" alpha="0.07" ratio="0.0011" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" alpha="0.07" ratio="0.965" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" alpha="0.00" ratio="0.9651" />
            </s:LinearGradientStroke>
        </s:stroke>
    </s:Rect>
    <!--- @private -->
    <s:Rect id="hldownstroke2" left="2" right="2" top="2" bottom="2" radiusX="2" includeIn="down">
        <s:stroke>
            <s:LinearGradientStroke rotation="90" weight="1">
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" alpha="0.09" ratio="0.0" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" alpha="0.00" ratio="0.0001" />
            </s:LinearGradientStroke>
        </s:stroke>
    </s:Rect>

    <!-- layer 7: border - put on top of the fill so it doesn't disappear when scale is less than 1 -->
    <!--- @private -->
    <s:Rect id="border" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" width="69" height="20" radiusX="2">
        <s:stroke>
            <s:LinearGradientStroke rotation="90" weight="1">
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" 
                                 alpha="0.5625"
                                 alpha.down="0.6375" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" 
                                 alpha="0.75" 
                                 alpha.down="0.85" />
            </s:LinearGradientStroke>
        </s:stroke>
    </s:Rect>

    <!-- layer 8: text -->
    <!--- @copy spark.components.supportClasses.ButtonBase#labelDisplay -->
    <s:Label id="labelDisplay"
             textAlign="center"
             verticalAlign="middle"
             maxDisplayedLines="1"
             horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="1"
             left="10" right="10" top="2" bottom="2">
    </s:Label>

</s:SparkSkin>
```

next we have our custom component named "container" like

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
            xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
            xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" xmlns:components="components.*"
             width="200" height="100">

    <s:TextArea id="text_box" width="100%" height="100%">

    </s:TextArea>
    <s:HGroup id="my_container" gap="20" width="100" height="40" verticalCenter="0" horizontalCenter="0">
        <components:test/>
            <s:button />
    </s:HGroup>
</s:Group>
```

and finaly we put that into the main application like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" height="100" width="200" xmlns:components="components.*" backgroundAlpha="0">
    <fx:Declarations>

    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[



            protected function mouseOverHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                this.myObject.my_container.visible = true;
                this.myObject.my_container.enabled = true;
            }

            protected function mouseOutHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                this.myObject.my_container.visible = false;
                this.myObject.my_container.enabled = false;
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

        <components:Comment id="myObject" mouseOver="mouseOverHandler(event)" mouseOut="mouseOutHandler(event)">

        </components:Comment>

</s:Application>
```

now if you try that, you'll see that the custom spark button component within this container is not clickable. however, the standard s:button component IS clickable, and i dunno why.

Comment: any ideas? couse i have no clue why a  extension of spark:button behaves so different from a spark:button instance

Answer (score 0):

If conB is a child of conA, then I would think mousing over conB would not trigger a mouseout on conA. The same basic event logic should still work...

Comment: well, i created a custom component (s:group) containing both conA and conB and removed  this.addElement(this.conA) since it made the elements disapper, and now the flicker effect is gone. 


Problem: now the buttons within conB are not pressable anymore. The strange thing about that is that if i use standard s:button buttons, they are pressable. but when creating a custom skin mxml based on the s:button component and using that one as button within conB, the button is not pressable anymore. even though NOTHING was changed within the custom skin s:button. Any Ideas?

Comment: It doesn't look like you have a new skin named "test", it looks like you have a custom component named "test", which I presume extends the spark Button component based on your description. I think I would need to see the code for that component and it's accompanying skin to take a stab at why it's behaving badly...

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not totally sure I understand your scenario...seeing the code would probably help, but I know if you have a skin on an element and you want that element to contain another element, the skin needs to have this:

```
<s:Group id="contentGroup" depth="25"> 
  <s:layout> 
    <s:BasicLayout/>
  </s:layout> 
</s:Group>
```

The contentGroup is something of a magic ID for skins to know that everything you nest in the skin's object (in other words, what the skin is being applied to) is not covered by the skin itself. Depth is the z-index, and the depth of the "contentGroup" group needs to be higher than anything else in the skin. Hope this helps.

Comment: hmm, no the z-depth cant be the problem since the basic spark button is working, see details below.